# Google Postman response timing

Tags: postman

I have a single post request that gets an object via our api. I am trying to time how long that takes so I did a collection and set iterations to 100 + and let it go. It runs fine and prints the total time for the run in MS but I want to see each ind post time. I think because its the same exact request sent over and over it does not print that?  I could really use that.

I did add a test to fail if its under a certain time in MS and that works but again does not print out response times from each request just pass / fail

Answer (score 0):

Export the test collection out of postman and there is an array with the timing of each iteration in milliseconds (example below from "Request Headers" test 5x).

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "times": [
                "189",
                "153",
                "164",
                "173",
                "168"
            ],
        }
    ],
}
```

Alternatively, you can run the test in newman (command line test runner) and export it as an html report and it might be easier for others to find the test results that you're referring to.